# What does "Failed to initialize App Engine SDK at [path]" mean, and how to fix it?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I'm using the the "Google Plugin for Eclipse", and installed both the "Web Toolkit SDK" and the "App Engine Java SDK" with it. Weirdly, the App Engine SDK can't be initialized while the Web Toolkit SDK works fine. Trying to point Eclipse to the root GAE SDK directory will cause the "Failed to initialize App Engine SDK at [path]" error. Downloading the GAE SDK separately will yield the same result.

I'm guessing the error is caused by a version problem?
Here is the setup:

- Eclipse 3.7 Indigo
- Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.7
- appengine-java-sdk-1.6.4 , appengine-java-sdk-1.6.5 (manual download)
- Java JVM 1.6
- Mac OSX 10.5, 32bit

Thanks!

Comment: You may find this [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/cc8c38dfd5527be2) helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the link, that send me in the right direction. It appears that you need the 64-bit version of Eclipse even on a 32-bit machine to run the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of Java that you are using.

For instance, if you have a default version of Java on your system that is older than the latest, regardless of what Eclipse is using as it's runtime or project JDK, the SDK may try and initialize with the default JDK on your OS.

For me, the issue was that my default JDK was Java 6, and GAE is not compiled to support anything lower than Java 7 at this point in time.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above check the versions of installed java sdks and java Jre. I faced the same error.

I have jdk1.7.0_45.jdk and and matching JRE i.e. jre-7u45, then set their path in eclipse->preference->java