# appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8 fails to initialize

Tags: google-app-engine

I get the following error

```
 The selected App Engine SDK is not valid: Failed to initialize App Engine SDK at /Users/<snip>/Desktop/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/
```

I followed the instructions in the book Programming Google Glass The Mirror API   by Eric Redmond
Eric Redmond. Programming Google Glass, P1.0 (Kindle Locations 2-3). The Pragmatic Bookshelf, LLC.

I then walked through the instruction on the google site the correspond to the same setup.

I am able to create the initial Android hello world app (for a nexus) but not able to create an app engine web app example because of the above error.  I've checked my path variables as best as I can tell and everything seems to be ok. Any advice?

Answer (score 8):

There are a few things that you will need to check:

- The latest version of App Engine SDK and Eclipse Plugin work with Java 7 only. So if you have an older version of Java , you will need to remove that and put Java 7.
- Ensure that your Eclipse JRE settings is pointing to Java 7 SDK.
- If the above does not address it still, you will need to modify the `eclipse.ini` file and point the VM to the JDK 7 SDK.

Comment: I would also like to add: all of the above helped for me, however, I had a 32 bit Eclipse installed. Once I upgraded to 64 bit Eclipse and applied all of the above, which can also be found in these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309109/what-does-failed-to-initialize-app-engine-sdk-at-path-mean-and-how-to-fix-i, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19972695/gae-not-initialized, then I was able to use the latest GAE SDK no problem.

Comment: That was it.  When I would query from the system panel about which java it was using, it would say Java 7.45 JVM.  However, when I asked on terminal the JDK was still at 1.6.  It was driving me nuts.  Installing the 7.45 JDK solved the problem.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Romin Thanks your **eclipse.ini** vm arguments solution solved my issue.